# Unable to parse JSON generated by PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have a php script which returns a JSON string.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'id' => '1',
'myarray' => array(
array('a' => 'a1', 'b' => 'b1', 'c' => 'c1', 'd' => 'd1'),
array('a' => 'a2', 'b' => 'b2', 'c' => 'c2', 'd' => 'd2')
)
);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The javascript code for parsing the JSON is

```
  $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://www.something.com/sendJson.php"
    }).done(function(json) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        alert(data['id']);
    });
```

But for the above code i'm getting this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: what's duration suppose to be?

Comment: Are you sure that the `json` variable in JS is the right string? How are you retrieving it?

Comment: please show us the contents of "json".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your ajax call. You have `dataType: "json"`, which means your string is already parsed in the callback.
So:

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://www.something.com/sendJson.php"
 }).done(function(json) {
    alert(json['id']);
 });
```